# Why 'str' Not Working in range. How can slove?

Tags: string, for-loop, input

Name=str(input("Enput Your Name:"))
for i in range(0,10,Name):
print(i)

#TypeError: 'str' object cannot be interpreted as an #integer

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

`range` function takes three arguments. `start`, `stop` and `step`, and all of these should be integer.

So `range(0, 10, 2)` will yield 0, 2, 4, 6, 8

In your case name is a `str` (or string).

I'm not sure what you want to achieve but if you want to print all letters of name, below code should work:

```
name = input("What's your name: ")
for i in name:
    print(i)
```